# How to link Autocad objects in Autocad

Tags: autocad

I want to link one value to another such that if I change the value of A, the value of B also follows that value of A.

That is,
B = A, where '=' is an assignment operator.[image]

Comment: Try engineering.stackexchange.com and tag question [computer-aided-design].

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Field Expression which references the value of `A`.

You can create the Field either using the `FIELD` command (which will create an MText object), or by right-clicking within the editable area of your annotation and selecting `Insert Field`.

Comment: or make the text a block.  insert the block in both locations.  When you edit the block to change the text, all matching blocks will also be changed